# How to use v-model with multiple in a custom select component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i have the following vue component

```
<template>
    <div id="input-div">
    <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <select :multiple="multiple" :value="value" @change="change($event.target.value)">
         <slot></slot>
    </select>
    <div class="error"><slot name="error"></slot></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'ha-select',
        props: ['label', 'value', 'multiple'],
        methods: {
            change(value) {
                this.$emit('input', value);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and since it is a select component i want it to be usable with `v-model` which works when the `multiple` attribute is not set but when i set multiple pass `v-model` an Array instead of appending the selected value to the Array, the array just gets replaced by the value of the current selected option. maybe it has something to do with the way i am emitting the `input` event. **So how do i create a custom `select` component with multiple support?**

Answer (score 6):

I've modified the code slightly to use a local variable bound to the select with `v-model` and emit the bound value. This results in emitting the array of selected values when `multiple` is true.

```js
console.clear()

const CustomSelect = {
  template: `
  <div id="input-div">
    <label v-if="label">{{ label }}</label>
    <select :multiple="multiple" v-model="selected" @change="$emit('input', selected)">
      <slot></slot>
    </select>
    <div class="error"><slot name="error"></slot></div>
  </div>
  `,
  name: 'ha-select',
  props: ['label', 'value', 'multiple'],
  data(){
    return {
      selected:this.value
    }
  },
}
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    albums: []
  },
  components: {
    CustomSelect
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <custom-select label="Pink Floyd Albums" v-model="albums" :multiple="true">
    <option value="1">Dark Side of the Moon</option>
    <option value="2">Animals</option>
    <option value="3">The Wall</option>
  </custom-select>
  <div>
    Selected Albums {{albums}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @zola did this answer your question?

Comment: This answer fixed an identical problem I was having.